# Assign NA to values in R 3.1.2 not working correctly

Tags: r, matrix, na, assign

I have a large 3 dimensional matrix (1440x720x15) "y" and want to assign NA to all values that are -1e30
when I do this, it assigns NA to everything including values> 0. Even when I try reassigning to 0 , all values become 0. What could be doing wrong?

```
dim(y)
[1] 1440  720   15
range(y)
[1] -1.00000e+30  2.67814e+28
y[y <  -(10^30) ]<-NA
range(y)
[1] NA NA
y[y =  -(10^30) ]<- 0
range(y)
[1] 0 0
```

Comment: You need `range(y,na.rm=T)` to exclude NA from the range calculation. Also `==` is not the same as `=`.

Comment: `y =  -(10^30)` does not return a logical vector. And `y == -(10^30)` still might fail to deliver the expected results. The safer approach would be to use `isTRUE` and `all.equal`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `range()` reports `NA` by default if there are any:

Try

```
y[ y <=  -(10^30) ] <- NA
range(y, na.rm=TRUE)
```